# Replace text between 2 particular lines in a text file using sed

Tags: regex, bash, text, awk, sed

Similar questions have been asked but they are for Powershell.

I have a Markdown file like:

```
.
.
.
## See also

- [a](./A.md)
- [A Child](./AChild.md)
.
.
.
- [b](./B.md)
.
.
.
## Introduction
.
.
.
```

I wish to replace all occurrences of `.md)`  with `.html)` between  `## See also` and `## Introduction` :

```
.
.
.
## See also

- [a](./A.html)
- [A Child](./AChild.html)
.
.
.
- [b](./B.html)
.
.
.
## Introduction
.
.
.
```

I tried like this in Bash

```
orig="\.md)"; new="\.html)"; sed "s~$orig~$new~" t.md -i
```

But, this replaces everywhere in the file. But I wish that the replacement happens only between  `## See also` and `## Introduction`

Could you please suggest changes? I am using awk and sed as I am little familiar with those. I also know a little Python, is it recommended to do such scripting in Python (if it is too complicated for sed or awk)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ sed '/## See also/,/## Introduction/s/\.md/.html/g' file
```